# Facebook Username Change History

Tags: facebook, username

I'm trying to get the username change log or username change history. I have tried to download profile information and the html file not contain any information about when the username changes.

Also I have check on the Facebook Web App in activity log, there weren't contain any information about username change history.

Is there any way to know the username change history including the username and the date when it changes?

Ps. My facebook username ending with the .ai from 2010 and suddenly the dot removed. I don't changes the username so I need to know when it changed.

Answer (score -1):

There is no easy solution to this - but there are two possible things you can try out:

Check Your Emails: Facebook usually sends an email notification when a change is made to your account, including username changes. Check the inbox of the email account associated with your Facebook profile for any notifications from Facebook regarding a username change.

Platform Policies: It's also possible that Facebook made the change due to their internal policies. For example, Facebook might have updated its username policies and automatically removed non-compliant characters from usernames, such as a period (dot). This could explain why your username was changed without your direct action. - Not sure about that -

Unfortunately, it may simply be that Facebook does not make this information available to users. In cases involving potential errors or unauthorized changes, contacting Facebook support directly is often the best course of action.